# Create sphere when screen tapped with adjustable radius in RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I'm creating an app in RealityKit that generates a shape based on user input. For example, if the user enters a radius of 0.1 meters, the shape(sphere for my case) will have a radius of 0.1 meters, same logic for 0.2,0.3, etc. The code all works, but I want to make it so the sphere appears when the user taps the screen.

Here is my code for the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var input: Float = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
            
            VStack {
                Text("Change the radius of your AR sphere")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("\(String(format: "%.1f", input)) meters")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(10)
                Button(action: { $input.wrappedValue += Float(0.1) })
                    {
                        Text("Increment by 0.1 meters")
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                
                Button(action:{ $input.wrappedValue -= Float(0.1) })
                    {
                        Text("Decrease by 0.1 meters")
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                NavigationLink(destination: ARViewContainer()) {
                    Text("View in AR")
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.top,30)
                }

            }
            
            
        }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        }
}
```

To create the shape when the user taps the screen, I created a Coordinator class which contains the HandleTap function. I get a weird error from the binding variable, though, saying **"Class 'Coordinator' has no initializers."**

```
class Coordinator {
    @Binding var input: Float
    weak var view: ARView?
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let view = view else { return }
        let location =  recognizer.location(in: view)
        
        let results = view.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
        
        if let result = results.first {
            
           let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
            let box = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generateBox(size: input),materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .black, isMetallic: true)])
            box.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .init(mass: 0.5), material: .generate(), mode: .dynamic)
            box.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            
            box.position = simd_make_float3(0,0.7,0)
            //static means body cannot be moved
            //dynamic means it can move
            //kinematic means user moved the object
            anchorEntity.addChild(box)
            view.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my code for the ARView, in which I call the coordinator function:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        let planeAnchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        let plane = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 1, depth: 1), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: true)])
        plane.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .init(mass: 1), material: .generate(friction: 1, restitution: 1), mode: .kinematic)
        plane.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        planeAnchorEntity.addChild(plane)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(planeAnchorEntity)
        
        arView.installGestures([.scale,.rotation], for: plane)
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap)))
        
        context.coordinator.view = arView
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator()
        }
    
}
```

I get another error when I call the Coordinator() function, saying **"'ARViewContainer.Coordinator' (aka 'Coordinator') cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers."**

I did a bunch of research into this error and how to make use binding variables, but haven't got it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.